# Software for constructing and visualizing 3D polyhedra

Tags: library, data-visualization, 3d

I plan to use the CGAL library to perform some 3D computations on polyhedra. The polyhedra need not be regular.

However, since CGAL does not come with visualization software, I would like to use a library which will help me visualize polyhedra. I would like to interact with my visualization, by spinning, zooming the picture.

OpenGL is an option, but it is far too low level. Are there higher-level libraries which would help me with this?

Comment: There exists a nice MATLAB based software for visualization of polyhedral sets determined by linear inequalities systems. See [https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19361/polyhedron-visualisation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19361/polyhedron-visualisation)

Answer (score 1):

[OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/) is also an alternative:

- Free software
- Custom programming language (possibly this is a drawback)
- Editor with integrated preview (or can use the preview with external editor)
- Cross platform support

Answer (score 0):

Probably your best bet is [Visual Python](http://vpython.org/).

- Allows you to numerically construct polygons and then display them, zoom in & out, rotate the scene, etc.
- Simple syntax & small installation
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform, OS-X, Windows & Linux
- Online version at [glowscript](http://www.glowscript.org/)